# How to export MS Access database along with schema?

Tags: mysql, ms-access, mysql-workbench

I have got a database in MS Access format and I want to export it to MySQL. I used [this](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php) tool to import the database to MySQL successfully. However when I try to do "Reverse Engineer" in MySQL Workbench to draw its schema, all I get is tables without relationhip links. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Relationships can only be drawn for foreign keys. If you don't have foreign keys (e.g. only MYISAM tables) then you won't get any relationship. Try the migration module from MySQL Workbench to see if that gives you more in your target schema (tho no promises). If all fails you have to manually add foreignkeys and thereby getting relationships.

Comment: The migration module seems to lack support for MS Access.

Comment: Oh, sorry, MS Access migration will come with the next version of MySQL Workbench.